# How to remove trailing spaces from. a variable in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script ,how do I remove the leading and trailing spaces for variable `TAG` ?

```
TAG=`find projectversions -build Current${BUILD} ${PROJECT}|grep ${PROJECT}`

echo "TAG  $TAG"
```

Comment: Which shell, specifically? The easiest way to do this in bash is with an extglob (`shopt -s extglob` at the top of your script, then `var=${var%%+([[:space:]])}`), but that's not available with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: #@CharlesDuffy - its `-bash`

Comment: In the future, use the bash tag in your questions, not the more generic shell tag, when an answer is intended to be used with bash.

Comment: (btw, you might consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds).

Comment: okay, how do I fix this in `bash`

Comment: See the link up at the top of the question (below the header "This question already has an answer here:"). If you have trouble applying those answers, [edit] to show how you tried to apply them, and how you determined the result to have failed, ideally with a [mcve] letting someone else reproduce the problem themselves -- that will result in a more specific and answerable question.